Executing `yq`, but `jq` gets executed
I am very confused.
I installed the Debian package yq
But if I call it, jq gets executed:
root@rescue ~ # echo '{"key": "value"}' | yq -p=json
jq: Unknown option -p=json
Use jq --help for help with command-line options,
or see the jq manpage, or online docs  at https://stedolan.github.io/jq

root@rescue ~ # cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"


On Debian yq is a wrapper around jq.
I was expecting this yq tool: https://github.com/mikefarah/yq
root@rescue ~ # apt show yq
Package: yq
Version: 3.1.0-3
Priority: optional
Section: utils
Maintainer: Debian Python Team <team+python@tracker.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 73,7 kB
Depends: jq, python3-argcomplete, python3-toml, python3-xmltodict, python3-yaml, python3:any
Homepage: https://github.com/kislyuk/yq
Download-Size: 19,2 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://mirror.hetzner.com/debian/packages bookworm/main amd64 Packages
Description: Command-line YAML processor - jq wrapper for YAML documents

Here are the instructions to install Mike Farah's yq: https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/?tab=readme-ov-file#install

There are two main implementations of YAML parsers called yq.

Mike Farah's yq, which is a utility written in Go.  Mike's yq also has the built-in ability to parse XML and a few other common structured document formats. This implementation of yq is common on Linux systems, but Debian has obviously opted for Andrey's yq instead.
Generic installation instructions: https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/#install

Andrey Kislyuk's yq is a utility written in Python that internally transcribes YAML to JSON and then applies the well-known jq processor to the converted input. Andrey's yq is also distributed with a couple of other tools for working with XML (xq) and TOML (tomlq) using jq expression syntax. This implementation of yq is common on non-Linux systems.
Generic installation instructions: https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/#installation


The command yq -p=json (read JSON input; note that JSON is a subset of YAML) has the same effect as yq -P (produce pretty-printed YAML output) with Mike's yq.  With Andrey's yq, the same effect is had using yq -y (produce YAML output).
Over the past years, Mike's yq has started to change its expression syntax to be more "like" Andrey's yq, possibly because the expression syntax of jq is so well-known by now. For simple expressions, the two YAML parsers can probably be used interchangeably, but they are mostly incompatible in terms of more complicated expressions and command-line options.
